# Set container div same height as that of iframe

Tags: iframe

I have a page that is calling an `iframe` from a different domain.

I want the container to be the same height as the `iframe`?

So I do not have to hard code the heights of all the elements on all screen sizes.

Make sense?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just set your container **height:auto !important;** , Hopefully that would be resolved your problem.

Thank you!